# Scrambled images after calling Camera.takepicture() on HTC Incredible

Tags: android, android-camera

Taking picture by calling [Camera.takepicture()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29) on HTC Incredible results in getting scrambled images. This problem does not appear on any other devices I´ve tested my application(Galaxy SII, Galaxy S, Nexus S). I haven´t been able to find the solution on my own as of yet...

Image linked: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4VE8.jpg  (need more reputation to post it)

This is how I save my imageData:

```
    static boolean StoreByteImage(Context mContext, byte[] imageData,
        int quality, String expName) {

    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File("/sdcard");
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    //String nameFile;
    try {

        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;

        Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
                imageData.length,options);

        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                sdImageMainDirectory.toString() +"/CapturedQRCode.jpg");

        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                fileOutputStream);

        myImage.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, quality, bos);

        bos.flush();
        bos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Anyone got a hint?